# ag-Grid: enableRowGroup is only valid in ag-Grid-Enterprise, your column definition should not have enableRowGroup

Tags: ag-grid

i am writing an an angular project with ag-grid and I want to try out the row grouping. Below is the test code from ag-grid website. However the grid shows regular grid and receive following in the debug window.

ag-Grid: enableRowGroup is only valid in ag-Grid-Enterprise, your column definition should not have enableRowGroup

Any idea, how to use trial version of ag-grid-enterprise?

Sample code: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/

Answer (score 2):

To use ag-grid-enterprise features first of all you need to install the following npm package:

```
npm install --save ag-grid-enterprise
```

Then, add the import to app.module.ts:

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
```

If everything is ok, you should see a message in the console that tells you there is no enterprise license key.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me.

```
// Add this to your component.ts
Step 1: import { AllModules, Module } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules'; 

// Add this to your component.ts
Step 2: modules: Module[] = AllModules;

// Add this to your component.html
Step 3: <ag-grid-angular [modules]=modules ....></ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score -1):

add below in app.modules.ts resolves the issue
import { AgGridModule } from '@ag-grid-community/angular';